# Open terminal and run command when open project

Tags: console, visual-studio-code

I have a project where I need to open multiple terminals and run a command in each terminal every time I begin to work on the project.

Is there a way to configure my project so when I open it, it will automatically open *N* terminals and run a command inside?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [custom task](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks) that runs a script (something like `openTerminal.cmd`) that opens all the terminals and configures them. Then you can [bind a key](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_binding-keyboard-shortcuts-to-tasks) to your task. So always when you hit that key it will start the task which executes your script which starts all the terminals.
Maybe there is also a setting for the tasks to run on startup of vscode. A list with all possible options can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-appendix)

Comment: I have been able to create a Visual Code task which executes a command. But I haven't figured out how to make the task create multiple terminals within Visual Code with a command.

Comment: That's good. Now as command you use your custom script. If you decided to write a `.cmd` (on windows) you can call the [`Start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command multiple times to start several terminals.